# React. onClick event not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my navbar, I have a button that will display a submenu (list of items) when clicked. Each item is their own child component and when clicked I want them to fire an event. The onClick event listener is not responding at all. However, other mouse events do apply (onMouseEnter, onMouseOut etc). Anyone might know what's up?

Child Component: NotificationItem.js

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { updateNotification } from "../../actions/notificationActions"

class NotificationItem extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this)
}

handleOnClick = (event) => {
    console.log("clicked")
    // let notificationId = this.props.notification._id
    // this.props.updateNotification(notificationId)
}

render(){
    let {avatar, description, seen} = this.props.notification
    return(
        <div
            onClick={this.handleOnClick}
            className="d-flex notification-wrapper" 
            style={ seen ? (
                { width: "250px", whiteSpace: "normal", padding: "0.5rem" } 
                ):( { width: "250px", whiteSpace: "normal", padding: "0.5rem", backgroundColor: "#d7e2f4" }
                )
            }
            >
            <div>
                <img src={avatar} style={{ width: "25px"}} className="mr-2 rounded-circle"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                {description}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Parent component: NotificationFeed.js

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import NotificationItem from "./NotificationItem"

class NotificationFeed extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

render(){
    let notifications = this.props.notification.notifications
    return(
        <div className="dropdown-menu">
            {notifications.map((notification, index) => {
                return(
                    <div key={index}>
                        <NotificationItem notification={notification}/>
                    </div>
                )
            })}         
        </div>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return{
    notification: state.notification
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NotificationFeed)
```

Edit: Something I noticed that might be of help. I'm using a bootstrap class to create this dropdown toggle-effect. When clicking on one of the items, the submenu closes immediately, without firing my desired event handler on the component.

```
                <span className="dropdown" id="notifications-dropdown">
                <Link to="#" className="nav-link text-light dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span 
                        key={Math.random()}
                    >
                        <i className="fa fa-bell"></i>
                    </span> { windowWidth < 576 && "Notifications"}

                    <NotificationFeed/>

                </Link>
                </span>
```

Comment: If you're defining the event handlers that way you don't need the `.bind` line. I'm not sure if that would prevent the handler from firing though.

Comment: @Herohtar. I tried without the binding, didn't have an effect either.

Comment: You are missing a closing brace `}` at the end of `NotificationItem` component. Not sure if it's a copy paste problem or it's also missing in your source code.

Comment: you don't need this line in your constructor `this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this)` (remove this)

Comment: @AhmadMaleki. Copy and paste problem.

Comment: @yourfavoritedev Check for errors in your browser console.

Comment: troubleshoot this like any other issue - remove that bootstrap class/data-dropdown-whatever stuff and see if the click works.  if so, bootstrap JS is likely altering the element, possibly replacing it with another (like what happens in other drop-down libraries)

Answer (score 5):

For those still interested, this was a problem with Bootstrap. Because the elements were created inside a Bootstrap dropdown it had some logic I couldn't see. Whenever I would click on an element, the dropdown closes before the event-handler would even fire.

Opted, to create my own dropdown instead. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onClick={ (e) => this.handleOnClick(e)}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You created an arrow function, you do not need to bind it in the constructor**

```
    import React from "react"
    import { connect } from "react-redux"
    import { updateNotification } from "../../actions/notificationActions"

    class NotificationItem extends React.Component{
    state = {}

    handleOnClick = (event) => {
        console.log("clicked")
    }


    //or do not use arrow function then bind in the constructor
     //constructor(props) {
          //super(props);
          //this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this)
     //}

   // handleOnClick(event) {
     // console.log("clicked")
   // }


    render(){
        let {avatar, description, seen} = this.props.notification
        return(
            <div
                onClick={this.handleOnClick}
                className="d-flex notification-wrapper" 
                style={ seen ? (
                    { width: "250px", whiteSpace: "normal", padding: "0.5rem" } 
                    ):( { width: "250px", whiteSpace: "normal", padding: "0.5rem", backgroundColor: "#d7e2f4" }
                    )
                }
                >
                <div>
                    <img src={avatar} style={{ width: "25px"}} className="mr-2 rounded-circle"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {description}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try change your code, now it's like method:

```
handleOnClick(event){
    console.log("clicked")
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not have an effect. :(

Comment: @VadimHulevich You are right, it's discouraged to use arrow functions as class methods; but it doesn't prevent code from working. The codepen you supplied works fine with or without arrow function style.

Comment: can you give me codepen example and i will find what's wrong